# How can I change the order of vcs changes in YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

As part of code review I need to look at the code changes in the order in which they were done. Some colleagues sometimes commit up to 5 changes before YouTrack fetches them. On the depending issue they are sorted by fetch date which I'm not interested at all.

Is it possible to change the sort order? If so - how?

Comment: You can sort VCS changes together with other activity records only by oldest/newest, which is based on time. There are no other options, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that they aren't sorted by oldest/newest. They are sorted by fetch time. Completely useless. I'm pretty sure that years ago they were sorted by commit time and after an update it was broken. Maybe the changes just were fetched more often then... :/